# How to find previous month's start, end dates in epoch integer format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using below query which is giving me correct result for finding the last day of the previous month in DATETIME format.

```
SELECT (DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())),GETDATE()))
```

However, I want the result in the epoch integer DATETIME format. Anyone knows how to get it?

I am on MSSQL - 2012 DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DATEDIFF()` function to get number of days from one date to another:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CAST(0 AS DATETIME),(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())),GETDATE())))
```

Also, you can use the `EOMONTH()` function to get the last day of a month in SQL 2012:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,CAST(0 AS DATETIME),EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())))
```

Your epoch start point can be adjusted, but 0 is a natural jumping off point in SQL Server.

Update: If you want '1970-01-01' to be your start date and you want it to be in seconds instead of days:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,'19700101',EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. For , DATE/TIME: 11/30/2013 12:00:00 AM PST
I need the result in seconds as: 1385798400

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, see update, you just need to adjust the start date and the unit of time you want to count.

Comment: At some point in the future this will stop working as the difference will overflow an `INT`, but that's more than 20 years away. The workaround to that would be first checking the days difference, then converting that to seconds, and adding to that the number of seconds since midnight.